# Is the function a closure or not and why?

Tags: javascript, closures

The function counter can be a closure?

```
let count = 0;

function counter() {
  return count +=1;
}

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
console.log(counter()); // 3
```

Comment: Yes. (filler for minimum comment length)

Comment: It might be worth reading this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Comment: This will help: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4.

Answer (score 2):

> The function counter can be a closure

Yes

closure is not only in nested function. The declaration of function in global scope is also a closure. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared

Answer (score 1):

> A closure is the combination of a function with references to its
>   surrounding state (the lexical environment) combined together.

Every time you create a function you create a closure at function creation time

```
let count = 0;

function counter() {
  return count +=1;
}

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
console.log(counter()); // 3
```

Function counter doesn't define any variable `count` still has access to the count because 
`count` has been defined in the scope in which the **closure** was created.Additionally **closures** are capable of not only reading, but also manipulating the variables of their `lexical environment` which you are doing in your case.So precisely your `function counter` solely is a not a closure ,

> function counter +its lexical environment is a closure

Comment: so, the answer YES or NOT?

Comment: updated my answer